# Selenium Internet Explorer WebDriver NoSuchElement Exception

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, nosuchelementexception

New to Selenium WebDriver, trying to get my firefox/chrome scripts working in IE, but it can't seem to locate any element.

For example here's the code I use to start the IE webdriver go to google and search the world 'blah'

```
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IEdriver");

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        IWebElement search = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
        {
            return d.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        });

        search.SendKeys("Blah");
```

Result: Google loads then test fails with a 'NoSuchElementException' - Unable to find element with the name==q

this works fine in firefox and Chrome.

*Using Visual Studio Ultimate C# and NUnit

Thanks,
Liz

Comment: Does it wait the 20 seconds? Have you set the protected mode settings correctly? What version of Selenium? What version of I? I'd also suggest you not use Google, it's too complex for a "starting page".

Comment: Yes, it waits 20s before timing out, selenium version 2.39. Sorry about google, just using it as an example.

Comment: @user3380737 What version of IE are you using?

Comment: WebDriver doesn't officially support IE 11 yet, please try with older versions of IE, read for more details on IEDriver https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: I switched to Internet Explorer 10 and ran the test. No change.

Comment: Take a look at [This][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770843/cannot-find-any-elements-in-selenium-using-internet-explorer-driver

they mention some IE security level options