# Unable to get element text using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Am using a piece of code below to get the text of some particular locator.

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Some locator"));
ele.getText();
```

This returns the string value,but only in IE browser it failed and worked in rest of the browsers i.e., Firefox and chrome.

Am facing this issue:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to get element text
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Please help me out in this and this exception in IE browser is also very inconsistent some times it passes and some times failed same code.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23795692/742269

Comment: i think both are different,am able to find the element but unable to get the text of it

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup is a great html parser, use Jsoup while you are using selenium they can get along each other.

```
String web_page = driver.getPageSource();//selenium driver is getting the whole page
Document xml_doc = Jsoup.parse(web_page); //jsoup parsing web page
String str= xml_doc.getElementById("Some locator").text();//get text and assign it to str
```

http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've a couple issues when getting text from elements so I get attribute "innerText" instead. Try code below:

```
if(element.getAttribute("innerText") != null)
    element.getAttribute("innerText").Trim();
else 
    element.getText().Trim();
```