# IE11 is failing to find element by using xpath while it works fine in Chrome in Selenium

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, xpath, automated-tests, internet-explorer-11

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td class="label" width="30%" valign="bottom">SOID:
        </td>
    <td class="desc" valign="top">123456789</td>
</tr>
```

**Iam intersted in the value "123456789"**

**Xpath**

```
".//td[contains(@class,'label') and contains(.,'SOID:')]/following-sibling::td"
```

**Code**

```
public string MyMethod()
{
    string soidXpath = ".//td[contains(@class,'label') and contains(.,'SOID:')]/following-sibling::td";
    IWebElement soidElem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(soidXpath));
    return soidElem.Text;
}
```

**With this xpath my test passes in chrome but fails in IE11 with the below...**

**Error**

```
Test 'H.Auto.RegressionSuite.TestCases.HN.HnLgoinTest.TC_Hn_login' failed: OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException : Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//td[contains(@class,'label') and contains(.,'SOID:')]/following-sibling::td because of the following error:
[object Error]
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.FindElementByXPath(String xpath)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClasse.<XPath>b__c(ISearchContext context)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.FindElement(By by)
0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 39.33 seconds (NUnit 2.5.10).
```

**Tried:**

1. *lowering the the security level in "Internet Options"*

> [Cannot find any elements in Selenium using Internet Explorer Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770843/cannot-find-any-elements-in-selenium-using-internet-explorer-driver)

*2. Added registry like below (Changed value of "iexplore.exe" from 0 to 1)*

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_DISABLE_INTERNAL_SECURITY_MANAGER
```

[image: Registry]

but no luck. Any idea or pointer how to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sometimes complex xpath are not resolved by the IE engine. Can you try this ".//td[contains(.,'SOID:')]/following-sibling::td" and check

Comment: Try this xpath `//table//tr/td[contains(text(), 'SOID:')]/following-sibling::td[text()='123456789']`  Note: Before execute this xpath provide few seconds of wait, so your driver may able to find the webelement. For wait use `Explicit wait` method.

Comment: Any specific requirement to track `td class="label"` and moving to `following-sibling::td` ?

Comment: Tried changing the xpath and adding explicit waits but result is indifferent.
Yes it's a requirement to make sure that i am getting the value of SOID.

Answer (score 1):

Xpaths are notorious for not working well in Internet Explorer.  Try using CSS Selectors.   Also, is it necessary to use IE?  Chrome and Firefox are optimal for Selenium.

Comment: Yes it's a requirement to run tests in IE. Will try CSS selector.