# Why is selenium acting bipolar with my code?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So, I wrote some code in Eclipse for selenium webdriver to find an element using "name" and send a word to that input box. This code works great on other browsers like Chrome and Firefox.

But for some reason,when I run the same code for IE, it's telling me that it can't find the element using "CSS". This is weird because I am not trying to identify the element using "CSS". I am using "name".

```
driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$MainContent$txtFirstName")).sendKeys(name);
```

Error message ( when run for IE ) says :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == *[name='ctl00$MainContent$txtFirstName']
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.8.0', revision: '924c4067df', time: '2017-11-30T11:37:19.049Z'
System info: host: 'WORKSTATION', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:33636/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find any elements in Selenium using Internet Explorer Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770843/cannot-find-any-elements-in-selenium-using-internet-explorer-driver)

Answer (score 3):

IEDriver is w3c compliant which means finding by name is not possible. To compensate for this, your selector is converted to css equivalent to finding by name by selenium.

See [the w3c spec](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#locator-strategies) which shows finding by name is not required for w3c compliant drivers.

Edit: Found where it is done in the [Java code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/W3CHttpCommandCodec.java#L205)

Comment: How come this was working fine before ? It was working on all browsers last week including IE even though it was very slow.

Comment: The first guess is always that it's a timing issue. Use an explicit wait for the element. Or if you're just debugging, put a sleep for a few seconds first and if that fixes it then supplement with an explicit wait. that or something changed on your system without you knowing it

Comment: I reset/repaired my IE and now it works! No more CSS element cannot be found error. But it's typing each letter horrendously slow. How do I fasten the typing speed on IE?

Comment: Use the 32 bit version. The 64 bit version is only to be used with IE9. See [the creator's blog post on the matter](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2014/09/screenshots-sendkeys-and-sixty-four.html)

Comment: Nice Analysis. (+1) for the Java Code